# how can i add head text in javascript alert dialog box

Tags: c#, javascript, html, css

I need to add Header text in javascript alert dialog box, that text having some forecolor and textfont will be bold. it is possible to create on javascript alert dialog box.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot modify the aspect of the `alert` dialog. It is browser specific. If you want to have custom popups you could take a look for example at [`jQuery UI dialog`](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or [`Twitter Bootstrap Modal`](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals). If you don't want to use third party javascript frameworks you could always roll your own implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this by using `alert` - it does not allow the option for styling.

You will have to create a `div` and show the alert manually.

**HTML**

```
<div id="alert" style="display:none">
    <p>
       Alert message!
    </p>
</div>

<button id="showAlert" onclick="showAlert()">Show alert</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
#alert p {
    color: red;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function showAlert() {
    var element = document.getElementById("alert");
    element.style.display = "block";
}
```

You can also use `jQuery` and `jQuery UI` to acomplish this and use `dialog`:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/